# RenderAction- / Cell-like functionality in Grails

Tags: grails

do you know if there's an equivalent in Grails to ASP.NET MVC's Html.RenderAction also found in Ruby on Rails as Cells?

The basic idea is that you can render *something* but the decision what to render is passed on to a different controller. So for example if you have a shopping cart's preview on the page that it's not taken from the current controller nor from data stored in session but from a result of another action in another controller (say ShoppingCartController).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it! It's called "include plugin". You install it like any other plugin and than you have the option to say:

<inc:include controller="shoppingCart" action="preview"/>

and it does exactly what it's supposed to do: render the outcome of preview action on ShoppingCartController.

Comment: Alternatives to the plugin:

Make use of GSP templates to "include" a portion of content from another controller:
[http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.2.3%20Views%20and%20Templates]
Use the <g:include/> tag:
[http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/include.html]

Comment: Thank you! That should have been the answer :D the g:include tag is what I've been looking for and it's in the base set of tags! Extraordinary!!!